# Side by side barplot in R with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used the next code in order to get a barplot representing the relative frequencies of my dataset.

```
ggplot(Votantes_Col,aes(x=Voto)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) +
  ylab("Frecuencias relativas")
```

[image: Plot 1]

Until here everything its ok. But now i need to add in the same chart another barplot like this one.

[image: Plot 2]

The final chart should compare the frequencies of YES/NO on both countries. The problem is that the two datasets have different length so i cant bind them in one data frame.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you mean dataframes have different number of variables? Also it is easier to help you if you share samples of your dataframes to reproduce your issue!

Comment: `library(patchwork);p1 + p2` where `p1` and `p2` are the two plots to put side-by-side.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want data from both countries on a single plot.

You are only plotting a single variable, so it is easy to join the data from the two countries together. Let us recreate your plots with some sample data:

## Plot 1:

```r
library(ggplot2)

Votantes_Col <- 
  data.frame(Voto = rep(c("No", "Si"), c(22, 79)))

ggplot(Votantes_Col, aes(x = Voto)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) +
  ylab("Frecuencias relativas")
```

[image]

## Plot 2:

```r
Otros_Votantes_Col <- 
  data.frame(Voto = factor(rep(c("Si", "No", "NS/NR"), c(65, 33, 1)),
                           levels = c("Si", "No", "NS/NR")))

ggplot(Otros_Votantes_Col, aes(x = Voto)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) +
  ylab("Frecuencias relativas")
```

[image]

Now all we need to do is take the `Voto` column from each data frame, and concatenate them together (ensuring they are first characters rather than factors). We put this column in a new data frame with a second column labelling which country they came from:

```r
df <- data.frame(Voto = c(as.character(Votantes_Col$Voto), 
                          as.character(Otros_Votantes_Col$Voto)),
                 Pais = rep(c("Pais_1", "Pais_2"), 
                            c(nrow(Votantes_Col), nrow(Otros_Votantes_Col))))
```

Now we simply use this to create our new plot. We will use the column `Pais` as the fill colour for our bars:

## Plot 3:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = Voto, fill = Pais)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)), position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) +
  ylab("Frecuencias relativas")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-09-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi Allan, thanks for your answer. That is what im searching for but i have two problems. The datasets have diferent number of observations and if i bind them leaving NA´s in one of them the relative frequencies would be modified. I need to keep the frequencies as if they were separated.

Comment: @DavidMarin in the method I show above it does not matter if the data frames are of different lengths. You are putting one "on top" of the other. Are you able to edit your question to share your data if you can't get this to work?